# Downloaded package (xxx.pkg) can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer

Tags: macos, installation, certificate

I'm the developer of an application which clients can download from my website (*lightroomstatistics dot com*). The first time the clients or I, on a different computer, start the downloaded installer I get the warning:

> "LR Analyzer.pkg" can't be opened because it is from an unidentified
>   developer."

However when running the package a second time, without changing anything, the installer runs fine. Also I can view the certificate info, see image 1.
My test machine is a MacBook Air and runs on OS-X El Capitan.

[image]

**Question: why do I get this message since I'm signed my application and package.**

Further I enrolled in the Apple Developer program and signed both my app and the package. BTW, the app itself never gives a warning, only the package I download.

For packaging I use Packages from WhiteBox.
After packaging I run this command to sign my package:

```
productsign --sign "Developer ID Installer: Dirk Gerard Peter Holtman" "./build/LR Analyzer.pkg" "LR Analyzer.pkg"
spctl --assess --verbose=4 --type install "LR Analyzer.pkg"
```

The result: Console feedback signing

[image]